# нужно что бы функция работала со всем файлом C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

написал функцию для шифровки текста банальным сдвигом. то есть берется текст из файла
шифруется и записывается обратно в файл, с чем она и справляется, но вот она умеет работать только с первой строкой. Что добавить или изменить что бы работала и с остальными строками?
сама функция:

```
ifstream file;
    file.open(name_file);

    char str1[255];
    string str;
    
    while (getline(file, str)) {
        strcpy_s(str1, str.c_str());

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)
        {
           str1[i] += 5;
        }
        cout << str1 << endl;
    }
    file.close();
```

Comment: считайте файл построчно, каждую строку шифруйте и записывайте построчно - или необходимо что-то другое?

Comment: посмотрите я изменил код, теперь он считывает и шифрует остальные строки. но я не знаю как построчно записать это всё в файл

Comment: Dafter Play ниже привел такой способ (запись построчно)

Answer (score 0):

ifstream служит для чтения файла, чтоб записать данные в файл необходимо использовать ofstream. Примерно так выглядит считывание значений из файла и запись в другой файл:

```
ifstream input(inputName);
ofstream output(outputName);
if (!input.is_open()) return -1; // Проверка открытия
string str;
while (true) { // Цикл для перебора всех строк
    // Code
    input >> str; // Считали строку из файла
    if(str.size()==0 && input.eof()) break; // Проверка, что файл кончился
    output << str; // Записали строку в файл
}
input.close();
output.close();
```

Рекомендую почитать информацию с этого [сайта](http://cppstudio.com/post/446/) думаю вы найдете все, что вас интересует

Comment: Распространённая ошибка у вас при проверке конца файла. Нужно это проверять **после** попытки чтения. `input >> str; if(str.size()==0 && input.eof()) break; output<<str;` такое будет по надёжнее.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, да, вы правы, уже засыпал и написал бред, сейчас все поправлю